# How can I make elements visible in C# Webbrowser?

Tags: c#, controls

HTML code (example):

```
<div class="clsA"><div class="clsA1">TEXT</div></div> <div class="clsB"></div>
```

I want make DIV which have class-attribute is clsA and their child-elements visible.
(both clsA and clsA1 appear).
I try

```
foreach (HtmlElement pageElement in webBrowser1.Document.All)
    {            
        if (pageElement.GetAttribute("className").ToLower() != "clsa")
            pageElement.Style = "display:none";
    }
```

but everything disappear.
Thanks

Comment: That is probably because your IF is always true.

Comment: Given your code, it seems to be working perfectly. (You've got an uppercase "A" in your comparison value.) But the code you have will not make anything visible. It will only selectively make things *in*visible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uppercase `A` in `"clsA"` will never match a to lower string, so you will set every item on the page to `display:none`.

Comment: He might want to set the element visible too with `else{pageElement.Style = "display:block";}`

Comment: Yes, it still does not work. I think clsA appear but clsA1 disappear

Comment: Well this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Spike/DzVxH/ effectively does what your C# is doing, so I suggest you step through your code in the debugger to work out what is going on.